# Using Regex how can i get a match between two words in a url?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a URL that looks like this,
"website/properties/sales/from-300000/up-to-800000/bed=1";

What I would like is to get two words from this URL and store them as variables;

The words I am looking to match are

"**from-300000/**" and "**up-to-800000/**"

What I have so far just gets the text between word and end of url. How can I match using Regex?

```
var url = "website/properties/sales/from-300000/up-to-800000";

var from = url.match(/(?=from).*$/g);
var to = url.match(/(?=up-to).*$/g);

console.log(from); // logs from-300000/up-to-800000/beds=1
console.log(to); // logs up-to-800000/beds=1
```

Comment: Do they always come in this order? Can there be anything in between?

Comment: Are you looking for both the words (from and up-to) and the numbers or just the numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a single regex: match *and capture* `from` followed by lazy-repeat of characters until you get to a forward slash, and then capture `up-to` until its slash with the same method:

```js
var url = "website/properties/sales/from-300000/up-to-800000/bed=1";
const [, from, upto] = url.match(/(from.+?\/)(up-to.+?\/)/);
console.log(from)
console.log(upto);
```

Comment: The `.+?` means match any character, *lazily* - that is, match as few characters as possible. So, at `from-`, it starts at `-`, then checks `3`, then `-`, etc, until it gets to `/`, which fulfills the next `\/` token. An alternative would be `(from[^\/]+\/)` but that's less efficient and a bit harder to read.

Comment: Here's regex to get only the numbers: `/\bfrom-(\d+).+\bup-to-(\d+)/`  (the `\b` means word boundary, `\d` means digits)